Getting a translation dynamically based on lang attribute
Im trying to add simple translations by utilizing the lang attribute.
Given the following:
var currentLang = document.documentElement.lang;
const translations = {
    en: {
        hello: "Hello World",
    },
    es: {
        hello: "Hola Mundo",
    },
};

Why does this work
console.log(translations.en.hello)

but not this
console.log(translations.currentLang.hello)

Im sure theres something simple im missing, but I cant figure out what. Thanks for any help in advance.

console.log(translations[currentLang].hello) will work

I was certain I had tried this, how silly. Thanks.
